# No periodic solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My math class is over but I never managed to solve the 
following problem:

Assume we have a K periodic solution $\lambda(t)$ to

$\dot{x}=f(x).$

Furthermore, $f(x)$ is locally Lipschitz continuous.
Prove: No nonconstant $K$ periodic solution $\lambda$ can be asymptotically stable.

What I tried: Since $\lambda$ is $K$ periodic, we know
$\lambda (t)=\lambda (t+K)$.

If two solutions $\lambda,\mu$ that satisfy the ODE are asymptotically stable, we have
$lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}|\lambda(t)-\mu(t)|=0.$

Inserting our periodicity for $\lambda$:

$lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}|\lambda(t)-\mu(t)|=lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}|\lambda(t+K)-\mu(t)|.$

Clarification: Locally lipschitz means, $f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous in every neighborhood $x$.

But what can I do now?

Comment: Where does the assumption that $\lambda(t)$ is $K$-periodic come from?

Comment: Can you also state the precise assumption for "locally Lipschitz" and "asymptotically stable"?

Comment: Hello, Michael! You are completely right! We assume that $\lambda$ is $K$-periodic from the start. My professor used the term locally Lipschitz interchangeably with Lipschitz continuity. Basically the conditions to apply Picard Lindelöf uniqueness axioms. I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: What if you consider $\lambda(t)$ and $\mu(t)=\lambda(t+K/2)$?

Comment: I unfortunately do not immediately understand how this would benefit us.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you tell me anything about $\mu(t)=\lambda(t +r)$ for some constant $r$?

Comment: Well, if $K$ is the period then $\lambda (t+r)=\lambda (t+r+K)$

Comment: Does $\mu(t)$ satisfy the ODE?

Comment: Yes it does satisfy the ODE

Comment: So now you are holding in your hand two particular solutions to the ODE.  So... [you can answer your own question below, which is standard practice based on hints.]

Comment: I think I see! Because of translation invariance of ODE's, both, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are valid solutions. Since they cannot intersect due to uniqueness and are both periodic with a slightly different period, the difference $\lambda-\mu$ will never converge, hence no asymptotic stability (but simple stability maybe). If this is correct then I will add an answer

Comment: I hope that you mean under "ODE" a _vector ODE_ (in other words, an _ODE system_).  Otherwise, the discussion is vacuous, see [Prove that an autonomous ODE f(x)=x' has no nonconstant periodic solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx), or [Proof by contradiction that there are no periodic solutions to x˙=f(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx).  Incidentally, in either case the Lipschitz assumption is not needed.

Comment: Yes, it was a vector ODE.