# Differential equation unknown parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

When we have a first-order differential equation such as

$$ y'(t) = y(t) $$

the *general* solution yields

$$ y(t) = c_1 \cdot e^t $$

where $c_1$ is a constant. Notice that the differential equation is autonomous ($y'$ does not depend on t in the equation directly). My question is now the following:

Can any function $y(t)$ be expressed as a first order autonomous differential equation? I am struggeling with the following equations

$y = t^a$ where a is an arbitrary real value and $y=ln(t)$. For the polynomial I tried

$$ y' = a \cdot t^{a-1}$$
$$ y' = a \cdot t^a \cdot t^{-1}$$
$$y' = a \cdot y \cdot \frac{d}{dt}ln(t)$$

but I am unable to express either this equation, nor $y=ln(t)$ itself in such a form, that the equation will only have $y$ or its derivative in it.

Comment: Do you mean, for every (say, $C^1$) function $y : (a, b) \to \Bbb R$ is there an first order autonomous differential equation, i.e. a function $F : y((a, b)) \to \Bbb R$ such that $y$ is a solution of the autonomous differential equation $z' = F(z)$?

Comment: Notice, for example, that for $y(t) = \log t$, we can write $y' = 1 / t$ as $1 / \exp \log t = \exp (-\log t)$, so $y(t)$ is a solution of the autonomous equation $y' = \exp(-y)$.

Comment: No, not any function can be expressed as **a solution of** an autonomous differential equation: it should be monotone.  See, e.g., [Proof by contradiction that there are no periodic solutions to $\dot{x}=f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642530/proof-by-contradiction-that-there-are-no-periodic-solutions-to-dot-x-fx).

Comment: @user539887 Thank you, you both actually helped me out. Is there a general rule of what order x has to be so that the equation holds for a given f(x)?

Comment: I don't know of any.

Comment: @user539887 But isn't $y' = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ periodic? Anyways, if your claim is right, then there should still exist an autonomous diffeq. for $y = t^a$ since it is monotone.

Comment: No solution of $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is periodic. You can easily find, adapting the method given by Travis, an ODE one of whose solutions is $y(t)=t^{\alpha}$.

Comment: @user539887 I am getting from multiple sources that $y = sin(c_1 + t)$ is a soultion to this ODE. I must say that I cannot verify this as I do not have the proper knowledge to solve such an equation by myself.

Regarding my question I found $y' = a \cdot y^{\frac{a-1}{a}}$. I am not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: You probably use some sources where formal calculations are made. Any (nonextendible) solution to $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ has the form \begin{equation*}\begin{cases}-1&\text{for }t\in(-\infty,-c_1-\tfrac{\pi}{2})\\ \sin{(t+c_1)}&\text{for }t\in[-c_1-\tfrac{\pi}{2},-c_1+\tfrac{\pi}{2}]\\ 1&\text{for }t\in(-c_1+\tfrac{\pi}{2},\infty)\end{cases}\end{equation*}(and you can see that the above functions are not periodic), plus the functions equal constantly to $-1$ and to $1$.  Your last formula is correct.